# SQL query for count of predicate applied on rows of subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a somewhat complicated SQL query to perform, and I'm not sure what the right strategy is.

Consider the model:

```
event
  foreignId Int
  time      UTCTime
  success   Bool
```

and suppose I have a predicate, which we can call `trailingSuccess`, that is `True` if the last `n` `events` were `success`ful.  I want to test for this predicate.  That is, I want to run a query on `event` that returns a count of `foreignId`'s for which the `event` was a `success` each of the last `n` times (or more) that the `event` was logged.

I am using Postgres, if it matters, but I'd rather stay in the ANSI fragment if possible.

What is a sensible strategy for computing this query?

So far, I have code like:

```
SELECT count (*)
  FROM (SELECT e.foreignId 
          FROM event e
          ...
          ORDER BY e.time ASC
          LIMIT n)
```

Obviously, I didn't get very far.  I'm not sure how to express a predicate that quantifies over multiple rows.

For hypothetical usage, n = 4 is fine.

Example data:

```
foreign_id    time     success
1             14:00    True
1             15:00    True
1             16:00    True
1             17:00    True
2             14:00    False
2             15:00    True
2             16:00    True
2             17:00    True
3             14:00    True
3             15:00    True
3             16:00    True
```

For the sample data, the query should return 1, because there are n = 4 successful events with foreign_id = 1.  `foreign_id` 2 does not count because there is a False one in the last 4.  `foreign_id` 3 does not count because there aren't enough events with foreign_id = 3.

Comment: Is `foreignId` a partition?  That is, is it a non-unique key, and each one needs its own count?  Could we get starting sample data and desired results?  Do you want to count _up to_ a maximum, or count _at least_ a minimum?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like foreignId is a partition, to use your terminology.  There will definitely be multiple unique rows with the same foreignId.  Descriptively, I want to count the events for each foreign id, see if that count is at least n, and then count the number of foreign id with at least n successful events.

Comment: What happens if there are 5 events for `1`?  Should that return a count of 5 (true events), or 4 (just the number we care about)?  What about if 5 (or 6) has `false` instead, what happens with that count?  I'm assuming you're actually using timestamps, and so have to worry about multiple days/rolling over midnight...

Comment: If the last 5 events are successful, then the last four events were successful, and the foreign_id should be counted.  I'm using date-times.  There's no need to worry about rollover.  But note, the query should return **1** if the last 4,5,6... events are successful for the sequence of events with foreign_id = 1.

Comment: That is, I want to run a query on event that returns a count of foreignId's for which the event was a success each of the last n times (or more) that the event (with type foreign_id = k) was logged.

Comment: Do you just want `foriegnId`s with the minimum rows, or do you also want the count of successful rows too?  That's currently still part of your question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  I want to count the number of foreignId's for which the last n (or more) events are successes.

Answer (score 2):

Try finding the latest "unsuccessful" entry fur each `foreignID`, using a simple `GROUP BY` clause. With this in a sub-query, you can join it back to the table, counting how many records there are (for each `foreignID`) that matches `foreignID` and has newer time.

Something like:

```
SELECT lastn.foreignID, count(*)
FROM 
 (SELECT foreignID, MAX(time) AS lasttime
 FROM event
 WHERE success = 'n'
 GROUP BY foreignID
 ) AS lastn
JOIN event AS e
 ON e.foreignID = lastn.foreignID
 AND e.time > lastn.lasttime
GROUP BY lastn.foreignID;
```

And you can experiment with left joins and the like to tweak it to your needs.

Comment: You need a `HAVING` clause in there for a minimum count, but yeah this should work.

Comment: Sure. I figured you would tweak it in all kinds of ways.

Answer (score 1):

The first derived table selects all foreignIds that have at least n events. The subquery checks if the last n events for each foreignId were all successful.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT foreignId
    FROM event        
    GROUP BY foreignId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= n
) t1
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT success THEN 1 END) = 0
    FROM event
    WHERE foreignId = t1.foreignId
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT n
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*)
from (
    select
        foreignId,
        row_number() over(partition by foreignId order by "time" desc) as rn,
        success
    from event
) s
where rn <= n
group by foreignId
having bool_and(success)
```

Comment: +1 this is close, but I think it needs to be wrapped in a derived table before doing count(*) because otherwise the count for each group will be returned

Comment: You're reporting multiple counts, but not saying which `foreignId` they belong to, which is problematic.  How would they know which ids had the minimum number?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up messing around on sqlfiddle for a while, until I arrived at this:

```
select count (*)
  from (select count (last.foreignId) as cnt
          from (select foreignId
                  from event
                  and   success = True
                  order by time desc
                  ) as last
          group by last.foreignId) as correct
  where correct.cnt >= 4
```

I guess the insight I'm adding is that every layer of "selecting" can be thought of as a filter on the inner selections.